# How can I use getServerSideProps in components

Tags: typescript, next.js

I need to use getserversideprops in components like I used in the pages. but I'm stuck how can I pass the sanity data into components?

**edit: solved I was missing the props :)**

Comment: could you tell us which page component you call `Clients`? That would help to find your problem.

Comment: ah sorry I just updated my question. I have no idea how I'm going to pass this sanity data with context & props :(

Comment: getServerSideProps is valid only on pages components, call it on the pages in which you use your component and pass the props to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Next.Js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props),

> `getServerSideProps` can only be exported from a page. You can’t export it from non-page files.

So, you have to call `getServerSideProps` inside a page component and not any other component.
You can use `getServerSideProps` inside a page, which wraps your component and pass data down to component.

Comment: that's literally what i wrote in the comments, was a whole answer needed?

Comment: @Nick First of all, I didn't see your comment, when I wrote this answer. Secondly, what I wrote aims to answer the question, that is why I decided to answer it and not comment it.

Comment: so like this? I get undefined on the console.

Comment: @JuliaSchafer 
`const teammembers = () => (<><TeamMembersComponent  /></>)`


You are not sending props to your `TeamMembersComponent`. Try 
`<TeamMembersComponent posts={posts} />`